# How do I get last input to column (ID)

Tags: c#, sql

I have this code that is suppose to get me the last registered MemberId from column but I cant get it to work, what have I got wrong?

```
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT top 1 * FROM Medleminfo ORDER BY MemberId desc";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            last_id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["MemberId"].ToString());
        }

        return last_id;
```

Output last_id is supposed to be used in this method:

```
public DataTable display_tiger_info(int member_id)
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT Medleminfo.MemberId, Medleminfo.Förnamn, Medleminfo.Efternamn, 
        Medleminfo.Adress, Medleminfo.Telefon, Tigerinfo.Tigernamn,Tigerinfo.Födelsedatum 
        FROM Medleminfo, Tigerinfo WHERE Medleminfo.MemberId = Tigerinfo.OwnerID ";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything useful.  Are you getting an error?  What do you expect to happen, and what is it *actually doing*?  Why are you executing a query as a non-query?

Comment: What do you expect as the output?

Comment: Ok, I expect last_id as output (Last member registered) to use in this method

Comment: By "last" do you mean by time or by the greatest number?

Comment: Again, are you getting an error? What is it actually doing?

Comment: @Tarbh First comment asked you to explain what actually is happening. ***You still have not done so.***

Comment: It all comes down to this line
dt = t.display_tiger_info(last_id);

Comment: You don't need the ExecuteNonQuery line. Also, this is a poor way to get the highest value in a multi-threaded DB because two queries can get the same result. You should use an auto-incrementing column type and let the DB assign the next value.

Comment: I want to use last_id so that i can get info from that particular user, see last in @SELECT..... WHERE Medleminfo.MemberId = Tigerinfo.OwnerID ";
I'd like to get member_id IN display_tiger_info(int member_id) as a parameter like ( WHERE " + member_id +" = Tigerinfo.OwnerID ";

Comment: Thing is last_id IS member_id in method above...I just need to get it right in sql Query.

Comment: My questions still remain unanswered. I give up.

Comment: So have you tried the answers below to get your id?  Also, you may have a problem with your second query because of the join, you will need to "AND Medleminfo.MemberId = " + member_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use the 'Max' function?  This is assuming that your looking for the largest number in the sequence.  The way your question is worded though would suggest that you should have a date column to search by instead.  Also if you want just one result then try execute scalar instead of putting it into a data table and going through all that extra work.

```
int id = 0;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using(var command = new SqlCommand("Select Max(MemberId) from Medleminfo", connection))
    {

        id = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issues is probably `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` according to the msdn [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected.

You will probably be wanting to use `ExecuteReader` in something like the following

```
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    con.Close();
}
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
//All you want is the member Id why get all the columns 
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT top 1 MemberId FROM Medleminfo ORDER BY MemberId desc";

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    last_id = Convert.ToInt32( reader[0]));
}
return last_id;
```

UPDATE: This code might solve your problem but I did not identify the issue correctly `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` should be removed it is not doing anything. `adapter.Fill()` should be executing the command and I do not know why you are not getting the expected response.